# Error possible XSRF attack in GWTP application

Tags: cookies, gwt, csrf, gwtp

I have a GWTP application (app1) calling another GWTP application (app2). The first sets a `SecurityCookie` as the second one.

If app1 is on new session, and this opens app2, everything works. If I close my browser and turn on app1 in new session without wiping the browser cache, app1 calls app2 and prints the following error:

> SEVERE: Cookie provided by RPC does not match request cookie, aborting
>   action, possible XSRF attack. (Maybe you forgot to set the security
>   cookie?)

Comment: Are you using `RandomSecurityCookieFilter` or `HttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter`? And when you say two separate apps do you really mean two separate apps? Because isn't communication between different apps what XSRF protection is meant to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

Without more info it's hard to provide an exact solution, but this is a known issue in GWTP, because the `RandomSecuritySessionFilter` changes the cookie each time a new RPC request is issued.

See [this github issue here](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/issues/587). It's rather long but worth the read if you want to understand the problem.

In my own app I dispatch about 5 async RPC calls at once and kept getting the same error as you in development mode, but much more rarely in production (due to the development server being so fast that calls return in a much more random fashion). So as a hack I turned off the cookie in development mode because it was making my life so difficult.